# file name references to "pizza.html" that does not exist in web content

Tags: html, servlets, web.xml, welcome-file

I am getting the following warning in web.xml in Eclipse Indigo which keeps the project from working.  I think my web.xml looks right so I don't understand why I am getting the warning.  The warning happens on the welcome file inside the welcome file list in web.xml.

here's the warning --> file name references to "pizza.html" that does not exist in web content

but that HTML file does exist in WebContent folder like so...

[image]

Here is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>BreakNeckPizza</display-name>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>PizzaControl</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.gmail.gmjord.PizzaController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>PizzaControl</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/pizza.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>pizza.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Can anyone shed how to resolve this problem?  Thank you.

Comment: Is `WEB-INF` a folder? And is `web.xml` inside it?

Comment: Yes.  WEB-INF is a folder and web.xml is inside it.

Comment: It's looking for `pizza.html` in the `WEB-INF` folder. That's why it can't be found.